# RVM と RBEnvの違いは？

Tags: ruby, rvm, rbenv

開発環境Macを乗り換えたのでRuby環境の刷新を行っています。
RVMかRBEnvのどちらかを利用しようと思っていますが、それぞれの違いや長所を教えて下さい。
これまではRVMを使っており、特に不便を感じていないのですがどうもRVMを離れてRBEnvに移行する人も少なくないなと感じています。

私自身の用途としてはRuby本体の開発は行いませんが、複数のRubyを切り替えて使います。
Gemを開発することはたまにあります。

似た趣旨の質問が英語版にもありますが少し古いようです。

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394338/how-do-rvm-and-rbenv-actually-work

Comment: rvmとrbenvのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RVM と rbenv の違いは

- RVM には Ruby のインストール機能がついている（rbenv は [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) を使う必要がある）
- RVM は cd を上書きする（rbenv は単純なシェルスクリプトによってつくられている）

という点があります。

RVM は単体で Ruby の環境が構築できますが、rbenv には Ruby のバージョン切り替えしかありません。そのため、`rbenv install` コマンドで Ruby を簡単にインストールするためには [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) のインストールが必要です。これは、OS X であれば [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/index_ja.html) 等のパッケージ管理システムを用いることで、 rbenv と同時にインストールすればさほど難しくありません。

また、RVM は cd を上書きしてしまうため、シェルの機能に手を加えることになります。rbenv は単純なシェルスクリプトによってつくられており、シェルの機能を害されることがありません。シェルの機能を上書きされると、何かトラブルがあった際に原因の切り分けが困難になります。

Comment: なるほど、CDのフックはドットファイルを読み込んでgemsetを切り替えているんですよね。理解しました。

Comment: はい。rbenv ではコマンドの実行時にRubyのバージョンを選択してコマンドを呼ぶので、cd をフックしていません。例えば、`rbenv which ruby` でrubyコマンドのパスが返ってきます。 https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/blob/master/libexec/rbenv-exec

Answer (score 3):

rbenv の公式 Wiki に ["Why rbenv?"](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Why-rbenv%3F) という記事があります。これによると、RVM は以下のことを**します**が、rbenv は以下のことを**しません** (現在の最新版である2017年2月の版から抜粋・編集・和訳しました)。

- シェルに読み込まれること。rbenv は代わりに `$PATH` を使います。
- `cd` のようなシェルコマンドをオーバーライドすること。
- Ruby のバージョン以外についてのコンフィグ・ファイルを持つこと。
- Ruby をインストールすること。rbenv では自前でインストールするか [ruby-build](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build) を使います。
- gemset を管理すること。rbenv では [Bundler](https://bundler.io/) を使うか、使えなければ [rbenv-gemset](https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset) を使います。
- 互換性のために Ruby ライブラリに変更を加えること。RVM では[いくつか](https://rvm.io/integration/bundler)の[ライブラリ](https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano)を使う際に注意が必要です。

Answer (score 2):

RVMにはrubygemを管理するgemsetの機能がありますが、rbenvには(標準では)ありません。

rbenvに移行するならgemの管理はbundlerに一本化するか、rbenv-gemsetと言うプラグインを別に入れる必要があります。